# Как избавиться от упоминания бота в Telegram? Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть такой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['помощь', 'help'])
async def help(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Список моих команд:\n`-` /help - помощь по боту')
```

Который выводит вот такое сообщение в Telegram:

```
Список моих команд:
- /help - помощь по боту
```

При нажатии на /help Telegram отправляет сообщение в виде:

```
/help@******_bot
```

Так как же убрать упоминание и сделать так чтобы при нажатии выводилось только `/help`.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY84k.png)

Comment: так происходит потому, что вы вызываете команду находясь в группе. Вне группы, если вы напишите боту напрямую, то такого не будет происходить. Могу предположить, что это сделано для того, чтобы не было пересечения команд, если в группе будет несколько ботов и у них будут совпадать названия команд. Так что ответ - убрать упоминание никак нельзя